# unable to see Sqlite database in my Android's FileExplore

Tags: android, sqliteopenhelper

I am creating a `Sqlite database` and when i want to see that `database` using `File_Explorer` at that time , i am not getting it in that location only two folders are present there : 
`Cache` 
, `lib`
, but `database` folder is not present there , but the point is that i am getting its `location` also , by `LOGS` ,

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_db__creation);

    database db = new database(this);
}

// -- SqliteOpenHelper class ( extended )!

public database( Context context ) 
{
    super(context, "New_one.db" , null , 2 );
    Log.i("2nd class : constructor","tushar");
    Log.i(context.getDatabasePath("New_one.db").toString(),"tushar");

    //(data base location )
    ///data/data/com.example.database_creation/databases/New_one.db
}

public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
{
    Log.i("2nd class : onCreate", "tushar");
    db.execSQL("create table timerecords " +"(id integer primary key, time text, notes text)");
}

public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) 
{
}
```

Comment: run code in emulator and try

Comment: Is database is created ?

Comment: If your devices is rooted then can proceed to see db of phone from file explorer in eclipse else run in emulator.

Comment: click on window which is your right side...and see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just follow these steps,

1. Using Devices, select the device/emulator where you are deploying your application.
2. Go to DDMS-> file explorer-> data->data->see your package name-> databases->here your database file.

Answer (score 0):

if u r using eclipse u can download this plugin just a copy paste of a .jar file :)
Just go through 
this [Link](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/04/18/sqlitemanager-plugin-for-eclipse/) follow instructions and see database in emulator DDMS of Eclipse.

Normally Database stored in `//data/data/<Your-Application-Package-Name>/databases/<your-database-name>` folder of the Android Device.

Answer (score 0):

Complete path of your Data BASE:

```
    ->file explorer
     ->data
      ->data-
       ->application package name
        ->databases
         ->your database file.
```

Answer (score 0):

First check it out whether your database is created or not, if it's working then run your application and go DDMS followed by this path -file explorer-data-data-application package name-databases-your database file.

Answer (score 0):

try this

you need to call `getWritableDatabase()` or `getReadableDatabase()` method only then you can create db in file explorer.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_db__creation);

    database db = new database(this);
   SQLiteDatabase sql =  db.getWritableDatabase();
}
```

and see your database here....in file explorer go inside ...`data/data/your package name/databases/New.db`

Comment: Why , we are using "db.getWritableDatabase()" !